# how to make textarea looks like input[text] on form invalid

Tags: css

This is how my textarea looks like on invalid, how to make it bit like textboxes (with smaller border arround)

[image: it looks like this]

It should look like the below image.

[image]

I used the below css but not working.

```
textarea:focus:required:invalid {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

textarea:required {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Design:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" placeholder="First Name" CssClass="mytxtCalendar required" MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" placeholder="Correspondence Address" Height="50px" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="mytxtCalendar required" MaxLength="120"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What do your textboxes look like? And what's your html like?

Comment: Can you post a working example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:-

```
textarea.mytxtCalendar.required {
    box-shadow: none;
}

    textarea.mytxtCalendar.required:focus {
        background-color: lightyellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
textarea:required {
    box-shadow: none;
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: Css I have used and paste here is working, I think my style-sheet was not binding on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add `outline: none;` to `textarea` it will be remove shadow for the `textarea`.

```
textarea:required {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;   //Added this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea:required{
    box-shadow:none;
    resize:none;
}

For Bootstrap elements you can define a classname too.
**Example:**

.custom_textarea{
    box-shadow:none;
    resize:none;
    height:37px;
}

<textarea class='form-control custom_textarea' name='text_name' required></textarea>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).